# Plot multiple lines on subplots with pandas df.plot

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by

Is there a way to plot multiple dataframe columns on one plot, with several subplots for the dataframe?

E.g.  If df has 12 data columns, on subplot 1, plot columns 1-3, subplot 2, columns 4-6, etc.

I understand how to use df.plot to have one subplot for each column, but am not sure how to group as specified above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of how I do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 6), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
df = df.div(100).add(1.01).cumprod()

df.iloc[:, :3].plot(ax=axes[0])
df.iloc[:, 3:].plot(ax=axes[1])
```

[image]